# Split a string while keeping delimiters and string outside

Tags: php, string, split, delimiter

I'm trying to do something that must be really simple, but I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm struggling with this one. What I want is to split a string containing 0, 1 or more delimiters (braces), while keeping the delimiters AND the string between AND the string outside.

ex: 'Hello {F}{N}, how are you?' would output :

```
Array ( [0] => Hello 
        [1] => {F}
        [2] => {N} 
        [3] => , how are you? )
```

Here's my code so far:

```
$value = 'Hello {F}{N}, how are you?';
$array= preg_split('/[\{\}]/', $value,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($array);
```

which outputs (missing braces) :

```
Array ( [0] => Hello 
        [1] => F
        [2] => N 
        [3] => , how are you? )
```

I also tried :

```
preg_match_all('/\{[^}]+\}/', $myValue, $array);
```

Which outputs (braces are there, but the text outside is flushed) :

```
Array ( [0] => {F} 
        [1] => {N} )
```

I'm pretty sure I'm on the good track with preg_split, but with the wrong regex. Can anyone help me with this? Or tell me if I'm way off?

Comment: Have you tried your second regex with the preg_split call above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't capturing the delimiters. Add them to a capturing group:

```
/(\{.*?\})/
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @PleaseStand for your answers, they both work! I read about parentheses, but didn't quite grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses around the part of the expression to be captured:

```
preg_split('/(\{[^}]+\})/', $myValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

See the documentation for [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).