# regex split string and keep delimiters in awk

Tags: regex, awk, split

As far as I can see, if I want to split a string with regex, and keep the delimiters in [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907772/split-but-keep-delimiter), [JavsScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689045/split-equation-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-javascript-and-keep-delimiters-t) or [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006590/split-a-string-while-keeping-delimiters-and-string-outside), I should use capturing parentheses / group in the regex; e.g. in Perl (where I want to split at a single digit and right parenthesis):

```
$ echo -e "123.123   1)  234.234\n345.345   0)  456.456" \
| perl -ne 'print join("--", split(/(\d\))/,$_));'
123.123   --1)--  234.234
345.345   --0)--  456.456
```

I'm trying the same trick in `awk`, but it doesn't look like it works (as in, the delimiters are still "eaten", even if a capturing group/parentheses are used):

```
$ echo -e "123.123   1)  234.234\n345.345   0)  456.456" \
| awk '{print; n=split($0,a,/([0-9]\))/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){print i,a[i];}}'
123.123   1)  234.234
1 123.123   
2   234.234
345.345   0)  456.456
1 345.345   
2   456.456
```

Can `awk` be forced to keep the delimiter matches in the array which is the result of split?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split()` in gawk e.g

```
echo -e "123.123   1)  234.234\n345.345   0)  456.456" |
gawk '{
    nf = split($0, a, /[0-9]\)/, seps)
    for (i = 1; i < nf; ++i) printf "%s--%s--", a[i], seps[i]
    print a[i]
}'
```

Output:

```
123.123   --1)--  234.234
345.345   --0)--  456.456
```

The version of the function in GNU awk (gawk) accepts another optional array name argument in which if present saves the matched separators to the array.

As noted in Gawk's manual:

```
split(s, a [, r [, seps] ])

Split the string s into the array a and the separators array seps on the regular expression r, and return the number of
fields.  If r is omitted, FS is used instead.  The arrays a and seps are cleared first.  seps[i] is the field separator
matched by r between a[i] and a[i+1].  If r is a single space, then leading whitespace in s goes into the extra array element
seps[0] and trailing whitespace goes into the extra array element seps[n], where n is the return value of split(s, a, r,
seps).  Splitting behaves identically to field splitting, described above.
```

Comment: Thanks for that @konsolebox! It would have looked great, but on my `gawk` version 3.1.7, I get "`gawk: fatal: 4 is invalid as number of arguments for split`" for your command. Is that something available only in a newer version?

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification, @konsolebox! Unfortunately, the `man gawk` for my 3.1.7 mentions only "`split(s, a [, r])`", so I guess this is a newer thing... Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Yes I just tried 3.1.7. It really doesn't support the new feature yet.

Answer (score 0):

As @konsolebox mentioned you can use split() with newer gawk versions to save field separator values. You could also take a look at FPAT and patsplit(). Another alternative would be to set the RS to your current FS and then use RT.

Having said that, I don't understand why you're thinking of a solution involving field separators when you could solve the problem you posted with just a gensub() in gawk:

```
$ echo -e "123.123   1)  234.234\n345.345   0)  456.456" |
gawk '{print gensub(/[[:digit:]])/,"--&--","")}'
123.123   --1)--  234.234
345.345   --0)--  456.456
```

If there's a different problem you're really trying to solve that'd require remembering the FS values, let us know and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: This did not work on Ubuntu GNU awk 3.1.8.  It just prints `1)` in the output, no `--1)--`

Comment: That means the RE isn't matching anything. Try changing `\d` to `[[:digit:]]`. Normally I would avoid`\d` for portability, etc. but the OP had it...

Comment: I just tested on an old awk (3.0.4) and on that at least `\d` was not recognized and so did not modify the output, but `[[:digit:]]` worked fine so I've modified my answer to just use that.